# Nested Concat function within Vlookup not working, Cant seem to find a syntax error

Tags: excel, vba, function, concatenation, vlookup

[image: data tab]

Hi,

I am trying to concatenate a certain filepath in order to change a subpath and part of the filename.

This is the function I am trying to put into cell D3

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A3,CONCATENATE("'G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and 
 Financials\1. Operating Entities\Arbors Major Hospital\2. 
 Financials\2018\",BB1,"\[Arbors"," ",BB2," ","2018.xls]Trial 
 Balance'")!$A$30:$H$100,8,FALSE),0)
```

This is the actual filepath on my machine: G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and Financials\1. Operating Entities\Arbors Major Hospital\2. Financials\2018\4. Apr\Arbors April 2018.xls

Assuming I have text in BB1 and BB2, 4. Apr and April respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put INDIRECT() around your concatenate like this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A3,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and Financials\1. Operating Entities\Arbors Major Hospital\2. Financials\2018\",BB1,"\[Arbors"," ",BB2," ","2018.xls]Trial Balance'","!$A$30:$H$100")),8,FALSE),0)
```

That will turn your concatenate from a string to a range so that the VLOOKUP has the parameter type it needs.

EDIT - it was missing a comma and brackets around this bit !$A$30:$H$100

Once it accepts the formula, you may find it does not actually do the lookup properly, if so we will need to break the formula down to make sure we have the right file location, then that we can get the right value from the Indirect, then once those work we can look at the VLOOKUP itself as it might need to be rewritten as an INDEX(MATCH...) instead.

EDIT - INDIRECT needs the files it pulls in to be open, otherwise it gives a #REF error.

Comment: Hey Daniel, it still is giving me the error, I added the error to the main question.

Comment: I think the square brackets should go around the whole path, so the next formula to try would be this one:  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A3,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and Financials\1. Operating Entities\Arbors Major Hospital\2. Financials\2018\",BB1,"\Arbors"," ",BB2," ","2018.xls]Trial Balance'","!$A$30:$H$100")),8,FALSE),0)

Comment: Yup it doesn't give me the error, but it doe give me a boolean as "FALSE" The path if we just use the concat function goes to the correct path, I think I put that in the main question.

Comment: Then try it without the IFERROR and VLOOKUP, so just this section, which will just pull back whatever is in cell A1 on the sheet. If that works then this part of the formula is ok:   =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'[G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and Financials\1. Operating Entities\Arbors Major Hospital\2. Financials\2018\",BB1,"\Arbors"," ",BB2," ","2018.xls]Trial Balance'","!$A$1"))

Comment: I am getting a #REF error, Isnt it because I am including the range at the end as string in my concatenate function?

Comment: Two things, You were right about the square brackets, so move the left one to just before Arbors again, then the second thing is that the files it pulls from need to be open for it to find them when you are using INDIRECT. I have set up a similar structure and it gives #REF unless I have the files open. I hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm, you think its possible to do this with vba?

Comment: It should work if you open all the external files though? We can try vba next if you like, as you know you can do anything in vba!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172613/discussion-between-yossup-and-daniel-bailey).

Answer (score 0):

Lets try a 2 stage process this time. You should be able to just manually link the VLOOKUP to one of your documents, so don't try to do anything clever, just a basic VLOOKUP where you use the mouse to select the range in the first of those documents (so you will need to open the first to be able to do that).

Once you have done that, close the external document and check the summary still pulls the number through correctly, maybe close and reopen the summary to check it still pulls that number.

Next we will have a look at the formula that it has written, and then we will use a separate sheet to build up all the other formulas for all the other documents, and then paste them in to the summary.

Getting one working is the first step, then instead of repeating that manually, we will automate creating the formulas for the others.

The reason for doing it this way is that a simple link to an external document will pull in that document automatically, but an INDIRECT formula will not, it will only pull it if it happens to be open.

Can you have a go and then paste here the formula for just the first row?

EDIT below:

yossup says "Here it is:"

```
=VLOOKUP($A3,'G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and Financials\1. Operating Entities\Arbors\2. Financials\2018\4. Apr[Arbors April 2018.xls]Trial Balance'!$A$34:$H$84,8,0)
```

Ok now we want to use the formula below which is based on your one above by popping it in a cell over on the right of that sheet somewhere, it does not matter where as we will delete it soon anyway.

```
="=VLOOKUP($A"&ROW()&",'G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and Financials\1. Operating Entities\Arbors\2. Financials\2018\"&BB1&"[Arbors "&BB2&" 2018.xls]Trial Balance'!$A$34:$H$84,8,0)"
```

Note the ROW() near the beginning that will move our reference to that A3 cell for us.

Now we can copy that formula down and it will write us out the formulas we need to copy over to the main summary. To do that I find it easiest to open notepad (all windows pcs have it, just look in your Start menu) and then copy those cells into notepad, then copy them back out and into Excel again. Because notepad knocks the clipboard down to just text, it pastes in as formulas, just what we want.

Now each cell has a direct link to the documents you want to pull from so it can get at them without them being open.

The only problem I can see is that if BB1 and BB2 are actually meant to be $BB$1 and $BB$2 then you have now lost your dynamic month changer. Hopefully they are not dynamic in that way and we are done. I can't tell from your screenshot so I am trusting you had it right. Otherwise we can try vba next.

Comment: Ok this is the function for the vlookup once the target document has been closed..   =VLOOKUP($A3,'G:\Financial\Facility Work Papers and Financials\1. Operating Entities\Arbors\2. Financials\2018\4. Apr\[Arbors April 2018.xls]Trial Balance'!$A$34:$H$84,8,0)